# Open-source app to record calls on android?

Tags: android, open-source, audio-recording

Do you know any trusted open source app to record calls on android? There may also be a calling app with such a feature. It is always safer when talking about job.

Answer (score 2):

Axet's **[Call Recorder](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.github.axet.callrecorder/)** is entirely open source and available at F-Droid, the place where you can find only open source apps. You can find its source code and some screenshots [in their GiLab repository](https://gitlab.com/axet/android-call-recorder). The app has been around for several years already, and is well maintained, its latest update was released just a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

[Call recorder for Android](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.callrecorder.android/) is also available at F-Driod.
does not seem to be maintained since 2015, but claims to works on Android 4.1+ devices.

[Source code can be found at Github](https://github.com/riul88/call-recorder-for-android)

Comment: Looking at the issues which often mention that it stopped working since Android 5.1 and a commit history without any commit for 7 years is not really promising. To call it "not as well maintained" is in my opinion not the correct term I would chose...

Comment: indeed, updated answer